# matplotlib custom legend with hatching

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I can seem to figure out how to pass the handles and labels from `matplotlib.patches.Patch` to the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


a_val = 0.6
colors = ['#EA5739','#FEFFBE','#4BB05C']


circ1 = mpatches.Patch( facecolor=colors[0],alpha=a_val,hatch=['\\\\'],label='Label1')
circ2= mpatches.Patch( facecolor=colors[1],alpha=a_val,hatch='o',label='Label2')
circ3 = mpatches.Patch(facecolor=colors[2],alpha=a_val,hatch='+',label='Label3')

fig,(ax) = plt.subplots()

ax.legend(handles = [circ1,circ2,circ3],loc=2)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Why is the legend blank in the above example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either I can't reproduce your issue, or you're missing a huge error. When I run your code above, I get an error about a `list` not being hashable, which seems to originate in the first `Patch` call's `hatch=['\\\\']` kwarg. Removing the list syntax (and using a raw string with 4 backslashes for extra effect) seems to work for me on matplotlib 2.0.2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


a_val = 0.6
colors = ['#EA5739','#FEFFBE','#4BB05C']


circ1 = mpatches.Patch( facecolor=colors[0],alpha=a_val,hatch=r'\\\\',label='Label1')
circ2= mpatches.Patch( facecolor=colors[1],alpha=a_val,hatch='o',label='Label2')
circ3 = mpatches.Patch(facecolor=colors[2],alpha=a_val,hatch='+',label='Label3')

fig,(ax) = plt.subplots()

ax.legend(handles = [circ1,circ2,circ3],loc=2)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: result of the above]

Is this what you're seeing?

Comment: It mush have been the `hatch=['\\\\']`.  Now things seem to be behaving.  Thanks!